# Как восстановить файл R.java в проекте Eclipse (ADT)?

Tags: android, eclipse

Как восстановить файл R.java в проекте Eclipse (ADT)?
После компиляции проекта и отправки его на виртуальное устройство (смартфон) по какой то причине не создался файл R.java, после этого проект не удается запустить из-за отсутствия данного файла.

Comment: Такое бывает. Попробуйте сделать очистку проекта и повторно собрать.

Answer (score 1):

Project -> Clean...

Comment: Если бы это помогло, то я бы не спрашивал. Увы и ах в MOTODEV Studio for Android "Project -> Clean..." не помогает...

Comment: Тогда пробуйте сменить версию JRE. Попереключайтесь между 1.5 <-> 1.6

Comment: 1.7.0_01-b08 стоит даже

Comment: После 30 раз Clean - Run все таки R.java создался, глюк непонятный, зависимости его появления и исчезания необнаружено

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй правой кнопкой по проекту и 
 **Android Tools** -> **Fix Project Properties**

Answer (score 0):

Имена файлов находящиеся в папке \res\ должны быть только в нижнем регистре.
(file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.])
Не соблюдение этого требования может быть причиной исчезновения файла R.java

Answer (score 0):

Если по Project -> Clean файл R.java не восстанавливается,
то нужно искать проблему в xmlках.

Где-то нарушена структура xml поэтому Eclipse не может собрать проект нормально.

Проверяйте AndroidManifest.xml в первую очередь.

Потом ресурсы res-values - values.xml/ style.xml